# Find sum of diagonal elements in array using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Need to find sum of respective diagonal elements using java 8 streams.

```
2d Array - { 
             { 1, 2, 3 },
             { 5, 6, 7 },
             { 8, 2, 3 }
           }

Output - Sum1 (1+6+3) = 10
         Sum2 (3+6+8) = 17
```

I know to do this by for looping array. Can this done using Java 8 stream ? If yes, how ?

Comment: have you tried anything on your own? how about sharing the implementation of your loops ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily done if you create an `IntStream` of the indices of the array, map each index to an element of the required diagonal, and sum the resulting `IntStream`:

```
public static void diagonalSums ()
{
    int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3},
                   {5, 6, 7},
                   {8, 2, 3}};
    System.out.println("first " + IntStream.range(0,arr.length).map(i -> arr[i][i]).sum());
    System.out.println("second " + IntStream.range(0,arr.length).map(i -> arr[i][arr.length-1-i]).sum());
}
```

Output:

```
first 10
second 17
```